# how to get next song duration in jplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

hi i have one question related jplayer music player right now i am able to get current song duration using this code
i try this code

```js
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").data("jPlayer").status.duration;
```

but now I want to get next song duration next of current song is there any way to get next song duration

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, as you can only get the duration of the currently loaded file. A workaround would be to load the file in to a hidden `audio` element which you can then read in the background.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's very possible. Each jPlayer uses separate audio tags. You can also do it with jPlaylist although it depends what you want.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson ah, my bad. I assumed jPlayer used a single player.

Answer (score 0):

Easy as:
`$("myNextPlayerIdHere").data("jPlayer").status.duration;`.

It's up to you though to determine how to find the next jPlayer Id selector because this is specific on your setup.